# This copy of the Install macOS Mojave application is damaged: Even After Correcting Time

Tags: mac, mojave, install, error

I was trying to do a fresh install of a macOS Mojave. But it ends up with an error 'This copy of the Install macOS Mojave application is damaged". I have downloaded multiple ios files and finally, I have tried by correcting Time. But still, the same error message is coming. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Download a fresh copy of the installer [from this link at Apple US:]( https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and tried many things.  system date was correct.  But only one website help me to fix this problem. Simple method and works on all version of macOS installation. I suggest to try this method. Because it works for me. 
https://www.computertipslaiju.com/2019/10/this-copy-of-install-macos-mojave.html

**Added by barlop**

The method at that link says

Disconnect wifi, then change the date, use the form mmddhhmmyyyy e.g. 042412302016

`sudo date 042412302016`

You need to disconnect wifi so the date won't automatically change.

The year makes all the difference.  For me, my year was set to the current year 2020 and I got that error trying to install High Sierra from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969

By changing the year of my system's date to 2016, I was able to start the installation.

For another person https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8RRm5N_n8s their year was some old date of 2001. Similarly, changing to 2016 made it work without that error.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer to include a summary of the content you're linking to, especially since it's a very quick tip that won't take much space at all. This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.

Comment: @Monomeeth  Their answer was very useful and solved it for me.  I improved their answer

Comment: Thanks @barlop much appreciated! :)